# Live image processing with OpenCV and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, raspberry-pi3

recently I'm struggling with speeding up image processing in OpenCV running on my Raspberry Pi 3 platform. I did face recognition application, but it works very slowly. I read many subjects about threading, multiprocessing and so on, but still I'm confused about it. I was testing it with face detection only to make it simplier. Here is my code:

**pivideostream.py - updating frames in thread**

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
from threading import Thread
import cv2

class PiVideoStream:

    def __init__(self, resolution=(640, 480), framerate=30):
        self.camera = PiCamera()
        self.camera.resolution = resolution
        self.camera.framerate = framerate
        self.rawCapture = PiRGBArray(self.camera, size=resolution)
        self.stream = self.camera.capture_continuous(self.rawCapture,format='bgr', use_video_port=True)
        self.image = None
        self.stopped = False

    def start(self):
        t = Thread(target=self.update)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        for frame in self.stream:
            self.image = frame.array
            self.rawCapture.truncate(0)

            if self.stopped:
                self.stream.close()
                self.rawCapture.close()
                self.camera.close()
                return  

    def read(self):
        return self.image

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True
```

**process_img_thread.py - main program**

```
from pivideostream import PiVideoStream
import cv2
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time


def detect_in_thread():
    # Start updating frames in threaded manner
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')
    thread_stream = PiVideoStream()
    thread_stream.start()
    time.sleep(2)

    # Read frames
    while True:

        # Original image
        image = thread_stream.read()

        # Full image - face detection
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            detected_face = cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

            # Region of interest - eyes detection 
            roi_color = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray,1.03,5,0,(40,40))
            for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,255),2)

        # Show computed image
        cv2.imshow('Threaded Camera OpenCV Preview',image)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break

    # Close image window and thread
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    thread_stream.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    detect_in_thread()
```

When I display raw frames from camera it's working great, but when I only add something in main program in order to process image, video speed is around 1 FPS :(.
Can someone help me?

Comment: face detection is an expensive task and raspberry pi is a slow decice. Maybe try a TK1 SoC instead, but no guarantee to be fast enough.

Comment: if you know the approximate size of faces in your images you can resize the images or limit the detection size.

Answer (score 0):

Micka's advices are very good.

I had issues with threading OpenCV in Python (not sure that's possible), but well done on threading the PiCamera frame grabbing.

I addition to the above try the following:

1. use "yuv" colour space instead of "rgb" and simply access the first (y - lumminance) channel to get the grayscale data, wasting less time fetching frames and converting from RGB to grayscale
2. try using an LBP cascade instead of HAAR (e.g. `/usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml`) - should a bit faster, but less accurate

Answer (score 0):

Capture frames in compressed formats such as **jpeg**, it will speed up the capturing process,

**ex:**

```
camera.capture_continuous(stream, format='jpeg', ....)
```

....